Cleaner way to write a CASE WHEN when entering different data for a column?
I added a new column named fledgling and I am trying to add the data in this column.



ID
birdname
height
wingspan
eggs
broods
incubation
fledgling
nestbuilder




1
Great Blue Heron
52
78
5
1
28
NULL
B


2
Mallard
28
3
10
1
30
NULL
F


3
Common Loon
36
54
2
1
31
NULL
B


4
Bald Eagle
37
84
2
1
36
NULL
B


5
Golden Eagle
40
90
3
1
45
NULL
B


6
Red Tailed Hawk
25
48
3
1
35
NULL
B


7
Osprey
24
72
4
1
42
NULL
B



I am writing the SQL code like so. is there a cleaner way to add this data?
    SET BIRDS.incubation = (case when bird_id = 1 then 60
                                when bird_id = 2 OR bird_id = 11 then 52
                                when bird_id = 3 OR bird_id = 5 OR bird_id = 15 then 80
                                when bird_id = 4 then 90
                                when bird_id = 6 then 46
                                when bird_id = 7 then 58
                                when bird_id = 8 OR bird_id = 10 then 24
                                when bird_id = 9 then 55
                                when bird_id = ....


if you have a data foundation in form of bird + fledging, you could create a pseudo table and join against it

MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server - please only tag the actual RDBMS you are using. And SSMS is a client interface, not even a RDMS.

And what is your goal? If the query solves your issue, then what, you want a few less lines?

I've removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your post to (re)tag the one you really using.

And SSMS is only a client UI, you want SQL Server (as I have done for you).

What is your data source? Unless you want to do multiple UPDATE statements your best bet is probably bulk loading the data source to a TEMP table, then joining t the temp table to do the update.

If you don't mind a few repeated result values, you can write the case expression in the form case bird_id when 1 then 60 when 2 then 52 when 11 then 52 ... end.  However, I think the pseudo table suggestion above is a better approach, or at least a join to a VALUES subselect.

where does the column bird_id comes from ? It's not in your sample data

you write that you want to populate column fledgling but in your attempt you update column incubation, so what is it ?

A slightly easier, more readable way is to use IN, like this:
...
WHEN bird_id IN (3, 5, 15) THEN ...
...

You can even do this for the single value checks if you want to have a consistent look for all WHEN clauses.

If you can bulk load your source data to a TEMP table, you can do that and then join your original table to the temp table:
UPDATE BIRDS
SET BIRDS.incubation = BIRDS_TEMP.incubation
INNER JOIN BIRDS_TEMP ON BIRDS.bird_id = BIRDS_TEMP.bird_id 


For relational perspective, always use a domain tables
Look how it easy and security and concise
creating a table
CREATE TABLE Incubation(BirdId int primary key,Incubation int)

insert data correlation
INSERT INTO Incubation
     VALUES (1,60),(2,52),(11,52),(3,80),(5,80),(15,80),(4,90)

and use in UPDATE
UPDATE Birds
   SET birds.incubation = inc.Incubation
  FROM Birds birds
 INNER JOIN Incubation inc on inc.BirdId = birds.BirdId


You can write
SET BIRDS.incubation = case bird_id 
                           when  1 then 60
                           when  2 then 52
                           when 11 then 52
                           when  3 then 80
                           when  5 then 80
                           when 15 then 80
                           when  4 then 90
                           when  6 then 46
                           when  7 then 58
                           when  8 then 24
                           when 10 then 24
                           when  9 then 55
                                ....
                       end

Or use Choose
select SET BIRDS.incubation 
                  -- 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12   13  14    15
  = choose(bird_id, 60 ,52, 80, 90, 80, 46, 58, 24, 55, 24, 52,null,null,null, 80) -- ....

